# React array not rendering after adding a component next?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to use setState() to update after the array psuhed numbers. The following code works and 83 show on the web page.

```
const children = [8];
class PersonList extends React.Component {

  state = {
    trigger: 0
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    children.push(3);
    this.setState({ trigger:1 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {children}           
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
<PersonList/ >,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But when I add a component next to {children}, setState() does not update the contents of the array. It only shows 8.

```
const children = [8];
class PersonList extends React.Component {

  state = {
    trigger: 0
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    children.push(3);
    this.setState({ trigger:1 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {children}
        <h1 className="title">Projects</h1>              
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
<PersonList/ >,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I can't think of what reason caused this. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an array in your jsx.

You need to loop over the array and render each component

Instead of

```
{ children }
```

do

```
{
    children.map(child => <div>{child}</div>)
}
```